# Why is Shikha Bandhan needed at the time of pooja?

Tags: belief, rituals, practice, puja

Why Shikha Bandhan is needed at the time of pooja? Is it related to God or due to any other reason and what would happen if we do not do shikha bandhan? What is the benefit? What to be done for those people who do not perform Shikha bandhan as prayaschittha?

Answer (score 4):

Shikha bandhan is carried out during Puja it is also called Shikha Vandanam.

From [Akhandjyoti](http://literature.awgp.org/akhandjyoti/1968/April/v2.14):

> **शिखा-बंधन**
>
> ॐ चिद्रूपिणि महामाये दिव्यतेजः समन्विते। तिष्ठ देवि शिखा मध्ये तेजोवृद्धि कुरुष्व मे॥

From [Gayatri Parivar](http://hindi.awgp.org/gayatri/sanskritik_dharohar/yagya_gyan_vigyan/yagyiya_karmakand/yagya_sanchalan/panchopchar_poojan/shikhavandanm):

<sup>Note: Translated into English</sup>

> **शिखावन्दनम्**
>
> It is believed to be **symbol of Gayatri**. Head is center of good thoughts into which only divine enter. **Determine that intenseness and vigorousness is growing**. Touch (with wetting two fingers) the location  of Shikha and after chanting following mantra apply the knot. Those who doesn't have Shikha, touch that location with such spirit/sense.
>
> **ॐ चिद्रूपिणि महामाये, दिव्यतेजः समन्विते ।।
>
> तिष्ठ देवि शिखामध्ये, तेजोवृद्धिं कुरुष्व मे॥**

From [Panch Sandhya](http://www.diya.net.in/spiritual_wisdom/gayatri/gayatri_mantra_sadhan/simple_and_safe_daily_gayatri_upasan/panch_sandhy)

> **Sikha Vandana**:
>
> Tie the sikha or touch this central spot (above the suture) on the skull. Close the eyes and chant the following mantra **with a determination that the divine radi­ance of Gayatri attracted thereby is being absorbed in the brain and is inspiring righteous thinking and illumination of  mind.**
>
> The Mantra:
> Om Cidrupini Mahamaye, Divya Tejah Samanvite| Tistha Devi sikha Madhye, Tejo Vraddhim Kurusva Me ||

From [Gurupuja](https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/2459053/1803522464/name/Dainik+Sadhana-English.pdf):

> **Shikha Bandhan:** (Tie your "Shikha" or put your right hand on your scalp)
>
> Now, put your right hand on your head **so that “Super Natural Power” which exists in the universe can be connected with you, so that you can gain necessary energy to do the “Sadhana”**. And chant this mantra.
>
> Chidrupini mahaamaye divya tej: samanvite |
> Tishth devi! Shikhaamadhye tejo vrudhim kurushva me ||

---

So, The answer of this question is in the following verse which is chanted during Shikha Bandhan during Puja.

> **ॐ चिद्रूपिणि महामाये दिव्यतेजः समन्विते। तिष्ठ देवि शिखा मध्ये तेजोवृद्धि कुरुष्व मे॥**

Which means <sup>I don't know Sanskrit much but I've tried to translate Sanskrit mantra in English (Need to improve)</sup>: Om, consciousness-form, having divine glory/energy | Be situated at the center of Shikha and increase glory/vigorousness ||

You can also find it at [Gayatri Upasana Vidhi-Vidhan](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80#.E0.A4.97.E0.A4.BE.E0.A4.AF.E0.A4.A4.E0.A5.8D.E0.A4.B0.E0.A5.80_.E0.A4.89.E0.A4.AA.E0.A4.BE.E0.A4.B8.E0.A4.A8.E0.A4.BE_.E0.A4.95.E0.A4.BE_.E0.A4.B5.E0.A4.BF.E0.A4.A7.E0.A4.BF-.E0.A4.B5.E0.A4.BF.E0.A4.A7.E0.A4.BE.E0.A4.A8).

---

For detailed explanation & significance on Shikha visit [this](http://www.indiadivine.org/why-do-hindus-wear-the-tuft-of-hair-called-shikha).

Also read [this](http://hindi.awgp.org/gayatri/AWGP_Offers/Literature_Life_Transforming/Books_Articles/gayatrimantra/lifemantra.1) (if you know Hindi).