# Did the Ancient Indian Rishis keep Shikha?

Tags: history, rishi, vedic-rituals, vashishta, shikha

[Shikha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikha) is a lock of hair on the crown on a shaven head. In the modern times, it is mostly worn by priests.

It is believed that traditionally all Hindu men kept Shikha, but later this was restricted to priests.

However, [Maharishi Vashishtha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasishtha) is described to have long hair which is tied to a bun.

I want to know whether Maharishis were exempted from this requirement, or was the Shikha not as widespread in ancient times as believed?

Comment: Yes the jatA or bun etc is a type of shikha Only. Vashistha etc were staunch vedics

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19442/7853

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi But doesn't Shikha require the entire head to be shaved, except the hair on the sahasrara part?

Comment: No sir. Its not needed. In fact there is a samskara called chuDAkarana samskara. Its not actually mundana but rearranging the tuft for making shikha. Also complete tonsure is against the Vedic principles.

Comment: Ohk thanks. No need to call me sir haha, I'm just a student. Btw, is there any rule for having no hair on face while reciting Vedic Mantras?

Comment: i dont think so. So are you going to learn vedas from path shala ?

Comment: I want to and would do so when time permits. I'm quite busy with college right now.

Comment: ok you can try to learn in weekends and holidays ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shikha is most important particularly to maharshis and seers because of their long term meditations/tapasya practices as their crowns or Sahasrara chakra are mostly open and thus vulnerable to common weather conditions and are susceptible to colds and heat and also to shield away entities.

It is a common phenomenon among long term meditators to have frequent “spiritual flu” if they don’t cover their crowns. Likewise, if you observe closely, most spiritual gurus in history or living do wear headscarfs of one form or the other.

And whearas the Kudumi or rat tail worn by most sadhakas is to remind them  for the purpose of contemplation or visualisation of the exact location of “Bindu Visarga” one of the energy center forming part of Chakradhyana.